# If-else function in php wont work

Tags: php, html, css

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['leveluser']=='user'{?>
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=?rajaampat=info><img src="icon/globe.ico" border="0px" width="12px" height="13px" > Home</a></li>
        <?php include "menu.php"; ?>
        <li><a href=logout.php><img src="icon/globe.ico" border="0px" width="12px" height="13px" > Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>

  <div id="content">
        <?php include "content.php"; ?>
  </div>
<?php}elseif ($_SESSION['leveluser']=='admin'){?>
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=?rajaampat=info><img src="icon/globe.ico" border="0px" width="12px" height="13px" > Home</a></li>
        <?php include "menu2.php"; ?>
        <li><a href=logout.php><img src="icon/globe.ico" border="0px" width="12px" height="13px" > Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>

  <div id="content">
        <?php include "content2.php"; ?>
  </div>';
<?php}else {?>
    <p><b>MAAF ANDA HARUS LOG IN do e</b></p>";
<?php}?>
```

i keep getting this error :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>' in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEB RAJA AMPAT\homedir\public_html\myadmin\administrator\media.php on line 98

Thx in advance for helping

edit : Cant find my answer in "PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?
"

Comment: What is  on line 98 - also note it can be in any of the include files

Comment: Also everything except the menu is the same for user and admin. Why not just `<?php include $_SESSION['leveluser']=='admin'?"menu2.php":"menu.php"; ?>` and ditto for content

Comment: `if ($_SESSION['leveluser']=='user'` is missing its closing parenthesis. Please use a better IDE which will highlight these types of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, check `if` condition, you have not closed parenthesis. Replace your `if` condition with following:

Please change it

```
if($_SESSION['leveluser']=='user'{?>
```

to

```
if($_SESSION['leveluser']=='user'){ ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['leveluser']=='user'){
echo '<div id="header">'.
    '<div id="menu">'.
      '<ul>'.
        '<li><a href=?rajaampat=info><img src="icon/globe.ico" border="0px" width="12px" height="13px" > Home</a></li>';
        include "menu.php";
        '<li><a href=logout.php><img src="icon/globe.ico" border="0px" width="12px" height="13px" > Logout</a></li>'.
      '</ul>'.
        '<p>&nbsp;</p>'.
   '</div>'.
 '<div id="content">';
        include "content.php";
  echo '</div>';
}
elseif ($_SESSION['leveluser']=='admin'){
echo '<div id="header">'.
    '<div id="menu">'.
      '<ul>'.
        '<li><a href=?rajaampat=info><img src="icon/globe.ico" border="0px" width="12px" height="13px" > Home</a></li>';
        include "menu2.php";
        echo '<li><a href=logout.php><img src="icon/globe.ico" border="0px" width="12px" height="13px" > Logout</a></li>'.
      '</ul>'.
        '<p>&nbsp;</p>'.
    '</div>'.
  '<div id="content">';
        include "content2.php";
  echo '</div>';
}
else {
  echo '<p><b>MAAF ANDA HARUS LOG IN do e</b></p>';
}
?>
```